# open a html table in a new window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html table below. Right now it shows directly. In stead can we add a button here so that when the user clicks on the button, this below table should open

```
<table border=1>
<tr>  
<th> Ratings </th> 
<th> Text </th>  
</tr>  
<tr>
<td> 1</td> 
<td > asd </td> 
</tr>   
<tr>
<td> 2 </td> 
<td > dfdsf </td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Use a `modal pop-up window` and put this code into the modal body

Comment: _"can we add a button here so that when the user clicks on the button, this below table should open"_ Yes, e.g. you can change the CSS display style.

Comment: You can open a new window via ``window.open`` and add content by assigning the return value of ``window.open`` to a variable and accessing the document through this variable (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: You could also just create an HTML file with just that table in it and link to it

Comment: You can make a new webpage, then in put the table in that webpage...after than make a button and put `addEventListener` of `click`to it. Which will trigger `window.open()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy way to accomplish this:

NOTE: Stackoverflow does not run the snippet correctly, download it to local and then run it.

```html
<html>  
<script>  
function openWindow() {  
var newtab = window.open("", "anotherWindow", "width=300,height=150");  
newtab.document.write("<table border=1><tr><th>Ratings</th><th>Text</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>asd</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>dfdsf</td></tr></table>");  
}  
</script>  
  
<body>  
<b> Click the button to open the new user-defined sized window </b>   
<br><br>  
<button onclick="openWindow()"> Open Window </button>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: THis is working. But i noticed that if you keep clicking on the button the rows are appended. Can we disable this feature. Like even if you click on it when the new window is opened, the rows should not be appended?

Answer (score 2):

You could open a new window then inject the table into it like this:

```js
const table = `<table border=1>
<tr>  
<th> Ratings </th> 
<th> Text </th>  
</tr>  
<tr>
<td> 1</td> 
<td > asd </td> 
</tr>   
<tr>
<td> 2 </td> 
<td > dfdsf </td> 
</tr> 
</table>`;

const popup = window.open();

popup.document.body.innerHTML = table;
```

Note: the snippet doesn't work on StackOverflow because the `iframe` policy disallows popups.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open )

```
function myFunction() {
  var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
  myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 
  100px 
  tall!</p>");
}
```